# Lookup on ListPage Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I've tried to create control with lookup so client can choose Vendor and filter grid with this data but I dont have any idea how to create lookup on ListPage when I cant override any method.

Answer (score 1):

A ListPage is a very special form only to search and find a record with few fields and parts to validate you're on the right record.

Also, a ListPage can be deployed as is on EP. So, you can't have any code in it as the web browser will not be able to run X++ code.

My first  answer will be to check if the field you want to filter on is currently in the query and showed in the ListPage. If so, you can filter using the standard filter already in your ListPage or activate the grid filter (ctrl+G).

If you really want to add a new control (which seems not to be in the ListPage best practices), you can look at interaction class. It's a helper class to add some code at server side in which you can handle the form. For example, modifying the query.